# How get files in HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, report, email-attachments, xls

I need to send a file 'xls' by email in annex.
I generate the file 'xls' and I want to attach this file and send it by e-mail, but I can not.
Xlwt'm using to generate the xls file, and this generated file I want to send email
"book = Workbook()...."

```
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/vnd.ms-excel")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name
    book.save(response)
    return response
```

So I saved the file, but that's not what I want, I want to attach.

Comment: If you want to send an email, why are you working on an `HttpResponse` object? And what is the `book.save(response)` supposed to do?

Comment: Xlwt'm using to generate the xls file, and this generated file I want to send email.